# TS type generation - @polkadot/api

Tags: polkadot-js

I've been trying to follow the documentation for generating types for `@polkadot/api` https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen/. However the generated files seem to be missing many types, revealed by `tsc`:

```sh
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts(87,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts(115,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemLimitsBlockLength'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts(119,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemLimitsBlockWeights'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts(123,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsRuntimeDbWeight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts(135,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpVersionRuntimeVersion'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(44,121): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportTokensMiscBalanceStatus'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(44,230): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportTokensMiscBalanceStatus'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(70,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(74,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(84,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaAppPublic'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(84,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaAppPublic'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(197,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletProcessValidationBinaryExpressionTreeBooleanExpressionSymbol'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(216,113): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(216,210): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(256,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(256,117): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(260,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(260,122): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(274,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(274,102): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportDispatchDispatchInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(274,154): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(274,192): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportDispatchDispatchInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(278,64): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportDispatchDispatchInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(278,115): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportDispatchDispatchInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(312,83): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(312,152): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(316,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts(316,158): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDispatchError'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(24,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpConsensusAuraSr25519AppSr25519Public'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(63,95): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletBalancesAccountData'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(72,97): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletBalancesBalanceLock'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(76,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletBalancesReserveData'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(99,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletGrandpaStoredPendingChange'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(120,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletGrandpaStoredState'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(174,97): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletPreimageRequestStatus'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(184,131): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletProcessValidationProcess'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(207,100): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletSchedulerScheduled'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(226,101): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletSimpleNftToken'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(246,95): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemAccountInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(258,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSupportDispatchPerDispatchClassWeight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(262,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpRuntimeDigest'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(276,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemEventRecord'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(293,71): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemPhase'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(305,75): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FrameSystemLastRuntimeUpgradeInfo'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts(352,94): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletCollectiveVotes'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(144,106): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(144,231): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(172,68): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaEquivocationProof'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(172,179): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpCoreVoid'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(172,233): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaEquivocationProof'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(172,269): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpCoreVoid'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(184,76): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaEquivocationProof'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(184,187): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpCoreVoid'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(184,241): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpFinalityGrandpaEquivocationProof'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(184,277): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpCoreVoid'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(367,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletProcessValidationBinaryExpressionTreeBooleanExpressionSymbol'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(367,161): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletProcessValidationBinaryExpressionTreeBooleanExpressionSymbol'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(367,337): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletProcessValidationBinaryExpressionTreeBooleanExpressionSymbol'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(405,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DscpPalletTraitsProcessFullyQualifiedId'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(405,211): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletSimpleNftOutput'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(405,237): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletSimpleNftOutput'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(405,354): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DscpPalletTraitsProcessFullyQualifiedId'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(405,410): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PalletSimpleNftOutput'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(451,102): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(451,227): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(534,145): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts(534,336): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SpWeightsWeightV2Weight'.
Error: src/interfaces/index.ts(4,15): error TS2306: File '/home/runner/work/dscp-matchmaker-api/dscp-matchmaker-api/src/interfaces/types.ts' is not a module.
```

It also generates an empty `types.ts` - I've not added any custom definitions.

`metadata.json` was generated with `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":"1", "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getMetadata", "params":[]}' http://localhost:9944` hitting our local node.

Is there something I'm missing or getting wrong in my setup?

**[PR showing the commands used and files generated](https://github.com/digicatapult/dscp-matchmaker-api/pull/43/files)** . Thank you

Comment: we are have a very similar problem. I noticed when i run the generator it gives an error ```ERROR: No lookup definitions found: Unknown file extension ".ts" for src/interfaces/lookup.ts```

Answer (score 3):

Try update to latest version of polkadot typegen and use this

```
"generate:defs": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm  node_modules/.bin/polkadot-types-from-defs --package dscp-matchmaker-api/interfaces  --input ./src/interfaces --endpoint ./metadata.json",
"generate:meta": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm  node_modules/.bin/polkadot-types-from-chain --endpoint ./metadata.json --output ./src/interfaces"
```

Comment: tried this an it didnt change anything. still cannot find all the types that are generated in the types-lookup.ts