# Generated Types Not Found

Tags: polkadot-js, types, typegen

Hi we are following along with the typegen docs on polkadotjs documentation.

and the generated code cannot find most the types.
an example line:

```
Called: AugmentedEvent<ApiType, [caller: PalletContractsOrigin, contract: AccountId32]...
```

The PalletContractsOrigin is not found
the types did get generated are in types/lookup
if i manually add an import

```
import {PalletContractsOrigin} from "@polkadot/types/lookup";
```

then that one is found. But there are many type errors.

```
Found 78 errors in 5 files.

Errors  Files
     6  src/interfaces/augment-api-consts.ts:119
    18  src/interfaces/augment-api-events.ts:166
    33  src/interfaces/augment-api-query.ts:23
    20  src/interfaces/augment-api-tx.ts:191
     1  src/interfaces/index.ts:4
```

here is my tsconfig section:

```
    "paths": {
      "my-lib-name/*": ["src/*"],
      "@polkadot/api/augment": ["src/interfaces/augment-api.ts"],
      "@polkadot/types/augment": ["src/interfaces/augment-types.ts"]
    },
```

i also get this error when running the generate

```
ERROR: No lookup definitions found: Unknown file extension ".ts" for src/interfaces/lookup.ts
```

Comment: can you please add repo ?

Comment: seams like so many people have issues with this. https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues/4752  , https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/ts-type-generation-polkadot-api  ,  just to name a couple

Comment: Of course there are problems. But currently I do not have any more problem generting types. Thats why I am asking for the repo I could help. Or at least for which node you need to generate types and I can help there.

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer using tsc for generation of types .. I am using **esno** or **tsx** because of ESM.

```
npx esno node_modules/.bin/polkadot-types-from-defs --package @mangata-finance/types/interfaces --input ./src/interfaces --endpoint ./metadata.json

npx esno node_modules/.bin/polkadot-types-from-chain --package @mangata-finance/types/interfaces --endpoint ./metadata.json --output ./src/interfaces
```

If you can show the repo I can look.